# Conjoint Experiment - Conditional Marginal means for categorical variable

Tags: marginal-effects, heterogeneous

I'm looking to adapt the codes shared in Andrew Heiss' amazingly detailed [page](https://www.andrewheiss.com/blog/2023/07/25/conjoint-bayesian-frequentist-guide/#finding-conjoint-amces-and-marginal-means-bayesianly)  on conjoint experiment, more specifically computing conditional marginal means for categorical variable using the dataset [candidate](https://www.andrewheiss.com/blog/2023/07/25/conjoint-bayesian-frequentist-guide/data/candidate.dta).

I would like to generate the same graphs, but instead of having two dichotomous variables (military - has served/not served; and political party - Democrat/Republican), I was wondering how I could use the same code if either or both my variables aren't dichotomous, in such a way that the graph output would make sense.

For example, let's say that there are four parties (Party A, Party B, Party C and Party D) and three military status (Not served/Served a couple of years/Served for more than two years), how can I adapt the group_diffs_terms matrix to compute all potential differences, for example:

Not served - Party A minus Party B
Not served - Party A minus Party C
Not served - Party A minus Party D
Not served - Party B minus Party C
Not served - Party B minus Party D
Not served - Party C minus Party D

and again for all military status, ideally all combined in the same graph. Sorry if it's an easy question, I am very very new to R.

Thank you!

```
##############################################################################
##############################################################################
### Load packages
library(tidyverse)        # ggplot, dplyr, and friends
library(haven)            # Read Stata files
library(broom)            # Convert model objects to tidy data frames
library(cregg)            # Automatically calculate frequentist conjoint AMCEs and MMs
library(survey)           # Panel-ish regression models
library(scales)           # Nicer labeling functions
library(marginaleffects)  # Calculate marginal effects
library(broom.helpers)    # Add empty reference categories to tidy model data frames
library(ggforce)          # For facet_col()
library(brms)             # The best formula-based interface to Stan
library(tidybayes)        # Manipulate Stan results in tidy ways
library(ggdist)           # Fancy distribution plots
library(patchwork)        # Combine ggplot plots

# Custom ggplot theme to make pretty plots
# Get the font at https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Jost
theme_nice <- function() {
  theme_minimal(base_family = "Jost") +
    theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
          plot.title = element_text(family = "Jost", face = "bold"),
          axis.title = element_text(family = "Jost Medium"),
          axis.title.x = element_text(hjust = 0),
          axis.title.y = element_text(hjust = 1),
          strip.text = element_text(family = "Jost", face = "bold",
                                    size = rel(0.75), hjust = 0),
          strip.background = element_rect(fill = "grey90", color = NA))
}

# Set default theme and font stuff
theme_set(theme_nice())
update_geom_defaults("text", list(family = "Jost", fontface = "plain"))
update_geom_defaults("label", list(family = "Jost", fontface = "plain"))

# Party colors from the Urban Institute's data visualization style guide, for fun
# http://urbaninstitute.github.io/graphics-styleguide/
parties <- c("#1696d2", "#db2b27")

# Functions for formatting things as percentage points
label_pp <- label_number(accuracy = 1, scale = 100, 
                         suffix = " pp.", style_negative = "minus")

label_amce <- label_number(accuracy = 0.1, scale = 100, suffix = " pp.", 
                           style_negative = "minus", style_positive = "plus")

# Data from https://doi.org/10.7910/DVN/THJYQR
# It's public domain
candidate <- read_stata("XXXXXXX/candidate.dta") %>% 
  as_factor()  # Convert all the Stata categories to factors

# Make a little lookup table for nicer feature labels
variable_lookup <- tribble(
  ~variable,    ~variable_nice,
  "atmilitary", "Military",
  "atreligion", "Religion",
  "ated",       "Education",
  "atprof",     "Profession",
  "atmale",     "Gender",
  "atinc",      "Income",
  "atrace",     "Race",
  "atage",      "Age"
) %>% 
  mutate(variable_nice = fct_inorder(variable_nice))

##############################################################################
##############################################################################
## Subgroup differences in AMCEs and Marginal Means
# No respondent-level characteristics in their data, so we'll invent a pretend column

## Code for generating fake respondent_party column
# Wrap this in withr::with_seed() so that the randomness is reproducible but the
# overall document seed doesn't get set or messed up
withr::with_seed(1234, {
  respondents_party_military <- candidate %>%
    group_by(resID, atmilitary) %>%
    # Find the proportion of times each respondent selected the candidate when
    # military service history was "Served"
    summarize(prob_select = mean(selected)) %>%
    filter(atmilitary == "Served") %>%
    select(-atmilitary) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    # If a respondent selected the candidate more than 60% of the time when
    # seeing that they had served in the military, there's a 90% chance they're
    # a Republican. If they didn't select the military candidate 60% of the
    # time, there's a 75% chance they're a Democrat.
    mutate(respondent_party = case_when(
      prob_select >= 0.6 ~
        sample(
          c("Democrat", "Republican"), n(),
          replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.1, 0.9)
        ),
      prob_select < 0.6 ~
        sample(
          c("Democrat", "Republican"), n(),
          replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.75, 0.25)
        )
    )) %>%
    mutate(respondent_party = factor(respondent_party))
})

candidate_fake <- candidate %>% 
  left_join(respondents_party_military, by = join_by(resID))

model_military_party <- lm(
  selected ~ atmilitary * respondent_party, 
  data = candidate_fake
)
tidy(model_military_party)



##############################################################################
## Conditional Marginal Means

# To be thorough and allow for any type of regression family 
# (logistic, multinomial) with any other types of covariates, 
# manually with our own regression model fed through 
# marginaleffects::marginal_means()
# By specifying cross = TRUE, get all combinations of 
# military service and party 
# (without it, we'd get separate marginal means for just 
# the two levels of military and the two levels of party)
party_mms_mfx <- marginal_means(
  model_military_party,
  newdata = c("atmilitary", "respondent_party"),
  cross = TRUE,
  wts = "cells"
)
party_mms_mfx %>% as_tibble()


# To find the differences in those marginal means, Want the differences between rows 2 and 1
# (Republican - Democrat for "Not served") and between rows 4 and 3 
# (Republican - Democrat for "Served")
group_diffs_terms <- matrix(
  c(-1, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 0, -1, 1),
  ncol = 2
) %>% 
  magrittr::set_colnames(levels(candidate_fake$atmilitary))
group_diffs_terms

party_mms_mfx_diff <- marginal_means(
  model_military_party,
  newdata = c("atmilitary", "respondent_party"),
  cross = TRUE,
  wts = "cells",
  hypothesis = group_diffs_terms
) %>% 
  as_tibble()
party_mms_mfx_diff

# Can plot these conditional marginal means along with the party-based differences
mm_party_plot1 <- party_mms_mfx %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(estimate_nice = case_when(
    estimate != 0 ~ label_percent()(estimate),
    estimate == 0 ~ NA
  )) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = estimate, y = atmilitary, color = respondent_party)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0.5) +
  geom_pointrange(aes(xmin = conf.low, xmax = conf.high)) +
  geom_label(
    aes(label = estimate_nice), 
    position = position_dodge(width = -1.2),
    size = 3.5, show.legend = FALSE
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = label_percent()) +
  scale_color_manual(values = parties) +
  labs(
    x = "Marginal means",
    y = NULL,
    color = NULL,
    title = "Marginal means by respondent party"
  ) +
  facet_wrap(vars("Military")) +
  theme(
    legend.position = "bottom",
    legend.justification = "left",
    legend.margin = margin(l = -7, t = -5)
  )

mm_party_plot2 <- party_mms_mfx_diff %>% 
  mutate(estimate_nice = label_amce(estimate)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = estimate, y = term)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0) +
  geom_pointrange(aes(
    xmin = conf.low, xmax = conf.high, 
    color = "Republican marginal mean − Democrat marginal mean"
  )) +
  geom_label(
    aes(label = estimate_nice), size = 3.5,
    nudge_y = 0.3, color = "#85144b"
  ) +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = label_pp) +
  scale_color_manual(values = "#85144b") +
  labs(
    x = "Difference in marginal means",
    y = NULL,
    color = NULL,
    title = "Difference in marginal means by respondent party",
    subtitle = "Positive differences = Republicans prefer the level"
  ) +
  facet_wrap(vars("Military")) +
  theme(
    legend.position = "bottom",
    legend.justification = "left",
    legend.margin = margin(l = -7, t = -5)
  )

mm_party_plot1 | mm_party_plot2
```